# Entity Framework - filter child entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I used entity framework with my example. I wanted to filter child entity but it break program at run time with error: "The entity or complex type 'CodeFirstNamespace.Customer' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query." Can anyone help me? Thanks.

```
public class Customer
    {
        public int CustomerID { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        //public virtual ICollection<Address> Addresses
        public List<User> Users { get; set; }
        public List<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
        public List<Order> Orders { get; set; }
        public List<CheckProduct> CheckProducts { get; set; }
    }

public Customer GetCustomerCheckProduct(string email, Byte checkType)
    {
        IQueryable<Customer> customers = context.Set<Customer>().Include("CheckProducts").Where(c => c.Email == email);
        if (checkType != 0)
        {
            var cus = customers.Select(customer => new Customer { CheckProducts = customer.CheckProducts.Where(s => s.CheckType == checkType).ToList() }).SingleOrDefault();
            return cus;
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Why _are_ you trying to construct a new customer based on an existing one? `Select(customer => new Customer...` ? You will, best case, en d up with an _empty_ customer, with only Checkproducts in it. If you cannot construct a customer without any other parameters, this will always fail.

Comment: Can you show me with more detail answer? I'm a newbie. :(

Comment: How much more detail do you want? What happens if you change your line that starts with `var cus =` to the line from my answer? :)

Comment: maybe this reference might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45336780/using-angularjs-to-implement-search-filter-on-crud-restful-json-web-call-to-enti

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want to find the first (if any) customer that has CheckProducts of the given type, why not use simply this?

```
var cus = customers.FirstOrDefault(c => c.CheckProducts.Any(cp => cp.Checktype == checkType));
```

Comment: It worked. yeah. Thank you so much. I have read a book and do this example. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

To filter a collection navigation property you can do the following:

```
var customer = <get customer entity>;

var filteredCheckProducts = context.Entry( customer )
    .Collection( c => c.CheckProducts )
    .Query()
    .Where( cp => cp.CheckType == checkType )
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: It throw an error at line .Collection : "Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'string' because it is not a delegate type". Please help me.

Comment: use "CheckProducts" then instead of c => c.CheckProducts